# SwiftUI 3 .searchable with Firestore

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to use the new `.searchable()` modifier with Firebase Firestore (or some other server), like the "Search" tab in the App Store App. I just found tutorials on how to filter local lists/arrays with `.searchable()`.
I know how to send a search request to Firestore using the `.onSubmit()` modifier. My question is how to show another View when the `.onSubmit()` is called or when a searchCompletion is clicked.

So if the search bar is empty, I want `SuggestionsView()` to show but if the user searched for something there should be `SearchResultView()` under the search bar, like in the App Store:

[image: Suggestions]

[image: Search Result]

I tried it with this code but this doesn't give the App-Store effect.

```
struct SearchView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if searchText.isEmpty {
                SuggestionsView()
                    .searchable(text: $searchText)
                    .navigationTitle("Search")
            }
            else {
                SearchResultView()
                    .searchable(text: $searchText)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SuggestionsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Suggestions")
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}

struct SearchResultView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Results")
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move searchbar to the NavigationView so it is not affected by the if else statement.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            NavigationView {
                if searchText.isEmpty {
                    SuggestionsView()
                        .navigationTitle("Search")
                } else {
                    SearchResultView()
                    
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}
```